# Is there any service in wso2 Identity server to get user Profile by passing session Token?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

my question is about  wso2 Identity server service.
Is there any service in wso2 Identity server to get user Profile by passing session Token?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you meant by the session token here ? IS has 2 type of sessions. One is the SSO session and the other is session obtained by authenticating to SOAP admin services (Tracked with the JSESSIONID)

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have.I found out it
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo
here we can pass Bearer openID auth token details and get the userinfo